How to write a high-quality data entry check in my fuel calculation code
I'm writing a term paper where you need to calculate the fuel at the gas station. The problem is that when entering a digit + any character, instead of an error, it takes the first value if it fits the condition.For example, if you enter "2weewdwfds[e[23", then the code will work because at first 2 is in the range of the condition, but it should output an error and ask for data entry again. Similarly, with regard to the beginning - between 95.92 and gas - if you write 1.1 or 1 \ 23b, he will think that I chose 95 fuel
type here

#include <iostream> 
#include <limits> 
 
using namespace std; 
 
// Constants for fuel prices 
const double PRICE_95 = 50;  // The price per liter for 95 gasoline 
const double PRICE_92 = 45;  // The price per liter for 92 gasoline 
const double PRICE_GAS = 30; // The price per liter for gas 
 
// Function for selecting the type of fuel 
double selectFuelType() { 
    int fuelType = 0; 
    cout << "Select the type of fuel:\n"; 
    cout << "1. 95 gasoline\n"; 
    cout << "2. 92 gasoline\n"; 
    cout << "3. Gas\n"; 
    cout << "Enter the fuel type number: "; 
    while (!(cin >> fuelType) || (fuelType != 1 && fuelType != 2 && fuelType != 3)) { 
        cout << "Input error! Please enter a number from 1 to 3.\n"; 
        cin.clear(); 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        cout << "Enter the fuel type number: "; 
    } 
 
    switch (fuelType) { 
        case 1: return PRICE_95; 
        case 2: return PRICE_92; 
        case 3: return PRICE_GAS; 
    } 
    return 0; // Fallback (should not be reached) 
} 
 
// Function for selecting the refueling mode 
int selectRefuelMode() { 
    int mode = 0; 
    cout << "Select the refueling mode:\n"; 
    cout << "1. Enter the number of liters\n"; 
    cout << "2. Refuel by amount\n"; 
    cout << "Enter the mode number: "; 
    while (!(cin >> mode) || (mode != 1 && mode != 2)) { 
        cout << "Input error! Please select 1 or 2.\n"; 
        cin.clear(); 
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        cout << "Enter the mode number: "; 
    } 
    return mode; 
} 
 
// Function for calculating the refueling cost 
void calculateRefuel(double pricePerLiter, int mode) { 
    double liters = 0, amountToSpend = 0, totalCost = 0; 
 
    if (mode == 1) { // Refueling by liters 
        cout << "Enter the number of liters: "; 
        while (!(cin >> liters) || liters <= 0) { 
            cout << "Input error! Please enter a positive number for the number of liters.\n"; 
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
            cout << "Enter the number of liters: "; 
        } 
        totalCost = pricePerLiter * liters; 
    } else if (mode == 2) { // Refueling by amount 
        cout << "Enter the amount you want to refuel for: "; 
        while (!(cin >> amountToSpend) || amountToSpend <= 0) { 
            cout << "Input error! Please enter a positive amount.\n"; 
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
            cout << "Enter the amount you want to refuel for: "; 
        } 
        liters = amountToSpend / pricePerLiter; 
        totalCost = amountToSpend; 
    } 
 
    cout << "You refueled " << liters << " liters. Total cost: " << totalCost << " rubles.\n"; 
} 
 
// Main function 
int main() { 
    double pricePerLiter = selectFuelType(); // Selecting the type of fuel 
    if (pricePerLiter == 0) { 
        cout << "An error occurred when selecting the fuel type.\n"; 
        return 1; 
    } 
 
    int mode = selectRefuelMode(); // Selecting the refueling mode 
    calculateRefuel(pricePerLiter, mode); // Calculating the refueling cost 
    return 0; 
}

I've already done everything I could)```


You could use std::getline which gets you a full line of input into a string and then you can verify if that string is valid.

The answer to this kind of question is always the same. 1) Read the input as a string. 2) Check that the string is valid input (whatever that means for you). 3) Convert the string to an integer. Sometimes steps 2 and 3 can be combined, but this depends on exactly what you are trying to do. In any case the key is step 1, read the input as a string.

Following the comments, here is a dirty version of what you want.
"I've already done everything I could" => I'm pretty sure that you can do even better that this code herebelow ;)!
double selectFuelType() { 
    string read_line;
    int fuelType = 0; 
    cout << "Select the type of fuel:\n"; 
    cout << "1. 95 gasoline\n"; 
    cout << "2. 92 gasoline\n"; 
    cout << "3. Gas\n"; 
    
    do{
        cout << "Enter the fuel type number: "; 
        cin>>read_line;
        if(read_line.length()>1 || read_line[0] < '1' || read_line[0] > '3')
        {
            cout << "Input error (read "<< fuelType <<") : Please enter a number from 1 to 3.\n"; 
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        }else fuelType = read_line[0] - '0';
    } while (fuelType < 1 || fuelType > 3);
 
    switch (fuelType) { 
        case 1: return PRICE_95; 
        case 2: return PRICE_92; 
        case 3: return PRICE_GAS; 
    } 
    return 0; // Fallback (should not be reached) 
}


Everything ingenious is simple
I simply changed the data type. Instead of struggling with numbers , I redid everything into a string)

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Константы для цен на топливо
const double PRICE_95 = 50.0;  // Цена за литр 95 бензина
const double PRICE_92 = 45.0;  // Цена за литр 92 бензина
const double PRICE_GAS = 30.0; // Цена за литр газа

// Функция для выбора типа топлива
double selectFuelType() {
    string fuelType;
    cout << "Выберите тип топлива:\n";
    cout << "1. 95 бензин\n";
    cout << "2. 92 бензин\n";
    cout << "3. Газ\n";
    cout << "Введите номер типа топлива: ";
    
    while (true) {
        cin >> fuelType;

        // Проверка на допустимые значения
        if (fuelType == "1") return PRICE_95;
        else if (fuelType == "2") return PRICE_92;
        else if (fuelType == "3") return PRICE_GAS;
        else {
            cout << "Ошибка ввода! Пожалуйста, введите номер от 1 до 3.\n";
            cout << "Введите номер типа топлива: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}

// Функция для выбора режима заправки
int selectRefuelMode() {
    int mode = 0;
    cout << "Выберите режим заправки:\n";
    cout << "1. Ввести количество литров\n";
    cout << "2. Заправить на сумму\n";
    cout << "Введите номер режима: ";
    while (!(cin >> mode) || (mode != 1 && mode != 2)) {
        cout << "Ошибка ввода! Пожалуйста, выберите 1 или 2.\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Введите номер режима: ";
    }
    return mode;
}

// Функция для расчета заправки
void calculateRefuel(double pricePerLiter, int mode) {
    double liters = 0.0, amountToSpend = 0.0, totalCost = 0.0;

    if (mode == 1) { // Заправка по литрам
        cout << "Введите количество литров: ";
        while (!(cin >> liters) || liters <= 0) {
            cout << "Ошибка ввода! Пожалуйста, введите положительное число для количества литров.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Введите количество литров: ";
        }
        totalCost = pricePerLiter * liters;
    } else if (mode == 2) { // Заправка по сумме
        cout << "Введите сумму, на которую хотите заправиться: ";
        while (!(cin >> amountToSpend) || amountToSpend <= 0) {
            cout << "Ошибка ввода! Пожалуйста, введите положительную сумму.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Введите сумму, на которую хотите заправиться: ";
        }
        liters = amountToSpend / pricePerLiter;
        totalCost = amountToSpend;
    }

    cout << "Вы заправились на " << liters << " литров. Общая стоимость: " << totalCost << " рублей.\n";
}

// Главная функция
int main() {
    double pricePerLiter = selectFuelType(); // Выбор типа топлива
    if (pricePerLiter == 0) {
        cout << "Произошла ошибка при выборе типа топлива.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int mode = selectRefuelMode(); // Выбор режима заправки
    calculateRefuel(pricePerLiter, mode); // Расчет заправки
    return 0;
}

